# std::thread maximum concurrent threads

Tags: c++, multithreading, concurrency, stdthread

I'm trying to understand a few basic concepts in `std::thread`, which I am still not confident about. The underlying question is:

*what is actually happening when I exceed the value of `std::thread::hardware_concurrency()`, like I did below?*

I know the method is just a hint, but in this case 8 should be accurate.  I see no warnings or errors, so what is actually happening?

I suspect this has something do with my lack of understanding of `join()` and `detach()`, which leads me to my second question.

I know that if I spin up threads without either a `join()` or `detach()` that I will get runtime errors.  As I understand it from reading and observations, `join()` causes the thread to block until it has finished execution, while `detach()` does basically the opposite, allowing the thread to run wild until it finishes, potentially opening a can of worms if that thread doesn't terminate on its own.

Based on what I observed, it seems that usage of `join()` and `detach()` are mutually exclusive.  Is this wrong? Why would I ever need to use `join()` and `detach()` on the same thread?

As far as my first question goes, I cannot even begin to guess.  I expected some type of runtime error, or some more obvious forced blocking.

```
#include <ctime>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <vector>

std::vector<unsigned> getNumbers(unsigned n)
{
    std::vector<unsigned> out;
    while(n > 0)
    {
        out.push_back(rand());
        n--;
    }
    return out; 
}

int main() {
    srand(time(nullptr));
    std::vector<std::thread> threads;
    unsigned maxThreads = std::thread::hardware_concurrency();
    std::cout << "Max threads: " << maxThreads << std::endl;

    unsigned tooManyThreads = maxThreads + 5;

    for(auto i = 0; i < tooManyThreads; i++)
    {
        threads.push_back(std::thread(getNumbers,(rand() % 10000 + 1)));
        std::cout << "Starting thread " << i << " (" 
            << threads.back().get_id() << ")" << std::endl;
        threads.back().detach();
    }

    for(auto i = 0; i < tooManyThreads; i++)
    {   
        if(threads.at(i).joinable())
        {
            threads.at(i).join();
            std::cout << "Joining " << i << std::endl;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: A C++ thread doesn't necessarily correspond to a real thread.

Comment: *"join() causes the thread to block until it has finished execution*" - That's not correct. It causes the *calling* thread (in your source, the thread running `main`) to block until the thread *being joined* finishes.  And fyi, all `hardware_concurrency` hints at is the number of concurrent *cores* that could/would allow free reign of thread execution. Ex. with 8 logical cores, you *could* (not necessarily *will*) have 8 truly concurrent threads of execution where the scheduler need not suspend one thread to run another.

Comment: And yes, joinable being false is a direct post-condition of detachment. [Read more about `detach` **here**](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread/detach).

Comment: "*Why would I ever need to use join() and detach() on the same thread?*" - you actually CAN'T do that. Calling `join()` on a detached thread, or calling `detach()` on a joined thread, will throw a runtime error. So you need to use one or the other, not both. You either join a thread to wait for it to finish, or you detach the thread and forget it even exists.

Answer (score 5):

You seem to be confused about what "thread" means in this context. There are two kinds of thread: `std::thread` is a [*software* thread](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thread_(computing)), while `std::thread::hardware_concurrency()` returns the number of [*hardware* threads](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multithreading_(computer_architecture)).

A sofware thread doesn't need a dedicated hardware thread, the operating system can and will schedule different software threads to share the same hardware threads. In fact, there are usually several orders of magnitude more software threads than there are hardware threads on the machine.

Answer (score 5):

At any given time there are several thousand threads running on your computer. Most of them come from other programs or processes, of which there are hundreds or thousands running in the background. (You can see them if you open TaskManager in windows, or type `htop` into a Linux command prompt).

So what is `std::thread::hardware_concurrency`? It’s the number of threads that can execute simultaneously. If you have 8 logical cores, you can only ever execute 8 threads simultaneously. All other threads are “paused”, at least until it’s their turn to run.

This may sound like a contradiction: how is it possible to have thousands of threads without thousands of cores? The answer is that the Operating System schedules threads. Each active thread gets a turn to run, and it happens sufficiently quickly that humans don’t notice delays, but those threads aren’t actually executing simultaneously.

Basically, `std::thread::hardware_concurrency` tells you the maximum possible speed up from using threads. If you have 8 cores, the maximum speed up from parallelizing using threads is 8x. It’s fine to start more threads than that, and many programs do so because they’re designed so that different threads handle different types tasks (like one thread may read/write files, and another thread may control the GUI, and another thread may process stuff in the background, and another thread may talk to the network), but it won’t actually make your program run faster.